# Retrieving JSON in jquery from a php script

Tags: jquery, json

I have this php script which when run outputs this. I cannot seem to fathom out how to access this in jquery I have tried varous methods from tutorials but no avail.

```
{"name":"photo1.jpg","id":"1"}{"name":"photo2.jpg","id":"2"}
{"name":"photo3.jpg","id":"3"}{"name":"photo4.jpg","id":"4"}
```

---

```
<?php

mysql_select_db('news') or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {    
    echo json_encode($row);
} 
?>
```

---

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {                      
$.getJSON('photo_get.php', function(data){

alert("Data" + data.name);

});
});
```

This outputs nothing.

---

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** valid JSON:

```
{"name":"photo1.jpg","id":"1"}{"name":"photo2.jpg","id":"2"}
```

It should look like this:

```
[{"name":"photo1.jpg","id":"1"},{"name":"photo2.jpg","id":"2"}]
```

What you should do is to push every row to some array and then serialize the entire array to JSON.

Eg. use something like this in the loop:

```
$array[] = $row;
```

and then serialize the whole thing outside of the loop:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be

```
<?php
$rows=array();
mysql_select_db('news') or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {    
    $rows[]=$row;
} 
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {                      
$.getJSON('photo_get.php', function(data){
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
alert("Data" + val.name);
});
});
});
```

as its an array

Comment: The php file now outputs [{"name":"photo1.jpg","id":"1"},{"name":"photo2.jpg","id":"2"},{"name":"photo3.jpg","id":"3"},{"name":"photo4.jpg","id":"4"}] But still no Alertbox

Answer (score 0):

you can push your response to array:

```
ArrayData = [];

ArrayData = data;
```

and then loop it:

```
for (var i; i < ArrayData.length; i++) {
   alert(ArrayData[i]['name'])
}
```

Comment: isint that what $.each(data does ?